React native IOS - xCode duplicate symbols when building archive - but building and running for IOS simulator is OK
Using xCode 16.1.
Building and running the app for iPhone 16 (for instance) is OK. Simulator runs the app OK.
But when trying to Product -> Archive (for "AAny iOS Device (arm64)"), then the build fails at Link phase because duplicate symbols.
Exemple of error:

duplicate symbol '_FIRLogError' in:
    /Users/pierdo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Sphinx/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/FirebaseCore.o
    /Users/pierdo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Sphinx/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore[13](FIRLogger.o)

Looks like the .o are generated twice, but can't figure out why...
Thanks for any help, I'm stuck looking for a solution...
Already tried to play with some of the build parameters of xCode, but there are so many...

Managed to remove the error: changed in xcode: settings -> locations -> Advanced -> Build location: Legacy.
